# Chrome extension using AWS Amplify federated sign-in

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I'm trying to implement a chrome extension based on React using AWS Amplify federated sign-in.

I already found this [tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/developing-chrome-extensions-with-amplify-authentication-be9b9e496a06) which works well as long I use the standard authentication from AWS Cognito. But when I try to implement the federated sign-in described [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/#setup-frontend), I only get the following error.

[image]

[image]

When using the chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow with Cognito all works well and I receive a token and can decode it.

Any best practices or ideas on how to solve this?